# Determine isolated singularities of $g(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{1-\tan(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometric-series, singularity

> Determine all isolated singularities and their type:
>   $$g(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{1-\tan(z)}$$

I want to do a Laurent series expansion for this function. So I got this: 
$$g(z)=\frac{z-\frac{1}{3!}z^3+\frac{1}{5!}z^5±...}{1-\tan(z)}$$

I'm not sure, how I can go further with this $\tan(z)$. The denominator is 0 for $z=\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi n, n\in\mathbb{N}$. So there are multiple singularities.  Or is this the wrong idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The isolated singularities of $g(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{1-\tan(z)}$ occur at the zeroes of $1-\tan(z)$, which lead to simple poles of $g$.

Note that there are also singularities at the zeroes of $\cos(z)$ (i.e., $z=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$) since $\tan(z)$ is undefined there, but these are removable since we may define $g$ as $0$.   And once removed, $g$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $z=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$.

As you correctly identified, the poles of $g$ are located at values of $z$ such that $\tan(z)=1$.  These values are roots of $e^{i2z}=i$ which implies that

$$z=\frac\pi4+n\pi$$

for all integers $n$.

---

We can construct Laurent series in each annulus for which $\frac\pi4+n\pi<|z|<\frac\pi4+(n+1)\pi$.  Note that when $n=0$, the Laurent series is a Taylor series.

Comment: The values where $\tan(z)$ is undefined, i.e. $z = \frac{\pi}{2} + n \pi$, are also isolated singularities - though those happen to be removable singularities.

Comment: @DanielSchepler And once removed, $g$ is analytic in each annular region $\frac\pi4+n\pi< |z|< \frac\pi4+(n+1)\pi$.  I've edited to mention this.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you! So to show this, I have to construct Laurent/Taylor series?

Comment: You're welcome.  You don't need to construct Laurent series to determine the location of the singularities.  We've done that.  You can proceed now to develop the Laurent series in any of the aforementioned annular regions.

Comment: @MarkViola why "the roots of $e^{i2z}=i$?

Comment: @gbox $$\tan(z)=1\implies \sin(z)=\cos(z)\implies \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{i2}=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\implies e^{i2z}=\frac{1-i}{1+i}=i$$